# Loading Django static files into css styles

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, static, django-templates

This is the part I am referring to in the question:

```
<div class="my-class" style="background: url({% static 'no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png' %}) center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
```

It is finding it:

```
[20/Aug/2020 12:54:30] "GET /static/no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png HTTP/1.1" 200 41235
```

However, it is not loading on my webpage.

I have `{% load static %}` in my html file.

Here is my settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="my-class" style="background: url({% static 'no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png' %}) center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
```

**Here is the problem.** just write like this, `url('no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png')`
And you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that with no luck unfortunately. i got: Not Found: /no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png
[20/Aug/2020 13:19:05] "GET /no_profile_pic/no-profile-pic.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12362

Comment: oh i am so sorry for that,but the convention is to write like above...maybe there are some other problems that had to be debugged..

Comment: Embarrassing answer, but i loaded in the wrong css file! Still appreciate the response djangotic.